# VTUNE results of CPU usage and Concurrency Histogram

Tags: performance, intel-vtune

In Vtune results what the numbers 0,1,2 (and 3) actually represent ?

What is the meaning of Blue bar over 0?

[image]

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I have already read.  The document is not clear to me. However Leeor's answer made things clear.

Answer (score 1):

It's a histogram - each column represents the portion of time you spend while the variable (the one appearing below the graph) is at any given value.

The left one states that you spend roughly 1/3 of the time with 0 utilized logical CPUs (fully idle), and 2/3 of the time with 1 logical core operating. You never reach 2 simultaneously operating cores.

In the same manner, the right histogram says you spend ~25% of the time with zero active threads, and ~75% with one thread (there's a negligible portion with 2 threads).

Note that the total times are slightly different, and the portion of fully-idle time also varies a bit - if this is taken over the exact same run, then this discrepancy might be explained by the difference between the time when a core becomes active (waking up from a low power state), and the moment that the OS can schedule a thread to actually start running on it.